# Try to set Django time field to 00:00:00 but dont want it to say midnight when I display it

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that has a Time Field called Duration. Format "hh:mm:ss" but its a running time,
not a clock time.  SO if there is no duration entered yet, I want the default value to be '00:00:00' but when displaying listing for the entry - it always get converted to midnight and displays 'midnight' for the duration field. Tried setting DATETIME_FORMAT and Time_Input_Formats in settings.py but that doesn't help....

Sometimes the entries could be created and have no duration yet....

Comment: How are you using your model in your template?

Comment: I apologize, I should have included more code - the template has the model.field name, so  {{ program.duration  }}.  The later post that was suggested works, adding the filter  ' {{ program.duration|time:"H:i:s"' . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to make your 'duration' field nullable (using null=True), rather than setting it to 00:00:00.

With that being said, if you have turned internationalisation on, your DATETIME_FORMAT setting will be getting over-riden ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#datetime-format)).

Something you could try, is using a time filter in your template, to explicity say how you would like the time to be displayed. E.g.:

```
{{ duration|time:"H:i:s" }}
```

See the formatting options [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Answer (score 2):

Django has a `DurationField` since version 1.8: [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#durationfield).
You might want to use that in place of `TimeField`.

*Also, even when asking simple questions like this, showing a few lines of code is always a good idea -so we are sure we talk about the same thing, and don't have to make assumptions about your what your implementation actually is.*